# Connect Flutter just_audio to Amazon Polly

Tags: java, flutter, rest, just-audio, amazon-polly

I am building a Flutter app which uses the just_audio library to play short voice prompts.

If I generate an mp3 file manually using Amazon Polly Text to Speech in the AWS console and then upload the resultant mp3 file to an S3 bucket, (after granting public access and copying the S3 object URL) then just_audio downloads and plays the audio correctly.

```
// Dart

final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
audioPlayer.setUrl('https://bucketname.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/say_someting.mp3');
audioPlayer.play();
```

However, I need the audio to be generated from text on-the-fly allowing voice prompts whose content is unknown until runtime. Hence I have also built a Java Spring Boot microservice which exposes an endpoint which calls Amazon Polly. Streaming is not necessary given the duration of the audio is less than about three seconds and the mp3 data about 15KB in each case.

```
// Java

@GetMapping(path = "/mp3", produces = "audio/mpeg")
public byte[] getAudio()
{

// Some piece of runtime text
final String whatToSay = "The time is now " + System.currentTimeMillis();

// Create a request for Polly to turn the text to audio
final SynthesizeSpeechRequest synthesizeSpeechRequest = new SynthesizeSpeechRequest().withOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mp3).withVoiceId(VoiceId.Amy).withText(whatToSay);

// Use SSML for intonation control
// synthesizeSpeechRequest.setTextType(TextType.Ssml);

final SynthesizeSpeechResult synthesizeSpeechResult = amazonPolly.synthesizeSpeech(synthesizeSpeechRequest);

// The content it typically just a few kilobytes, so we can just collect it and send it as an array of bytes 
final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(synthesizeSpeechResult.getAudioStream(), outputStream);
return outputStream.toByteArray();

}
```

If I deploy this microservice to Elastic Beanstalk and access the endpoint with a browser then the browser plays the audio correctly. If I download the mp3 from this endpoint then the mp3 file can be played from Quicktime. So there does not appear to be anything wrong server-side.

```
// Dart

final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
audioPlayer.setUrl('https://my-domain/mp3');
audioPlayer.play();
```

A problem occurs when I point the just_audio player to the endpoint. An exception is thrown with the message ‘source error’.

How can I get my Spring Boot app and the just_audio player to work together?

I have tried stepping through the just_audio source to see if I can find out any more detail as to the cause of the problem, but the trail goes cold as the error originates in async code and is attached to a Future.

I have tried including an empty header map while setting the url because I can see just_audio checks for this.

I have tried the flutter_tts package but I cannot find any support for controlling the emphasis of given words in a sentence. (Amazon Polly supports SSML and hence offers fine control of the intonation).

I have tried streaming the output of Amazon Polly to the Response stream instead of buffering the audio data.

I have set up a (temporary) URL which demonstrates the problem here:

[Polly mp3 server endpoint](http://pollyjustaudio-env.eba-cn2msugj.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/audio/test.mp3)

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 08 Feb 2024 07:59:14 GMT
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Content-Length: 50043
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Is the README troubleshooting section of any help?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to this: [link](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/blob/minor/just_audio/README.md#troubleshooting).

Polly does not offer M4A as recommended, but it looks like MP3 would only be a problem with files a lot larger than 20KB. 

Server headers: I was not setting the content length previously so I have rectified this now. 

`response.setContentLength(outputStream.size());
response.setContentType("audio/mpeg");`

However, `audioPlayer.setUrl` still throws an exception ‘Source error’.

Comment: Given the possible causes described in the troubleshooting section, could you edit your question to provide information relevant to those possible causes? For example, can you provide the response headers? (If you provide the actual URL, I could see the headers myself and also analyse the audio file encoding.)

Comment: Thanks again Ryan. I have added a link at the end of the question as you suggested.

Comment: Can you paste the response headers into your question? If the URL is only temporary, people need something permanent in the question. From the response headers, people will be able to tell you which part of your response headers do not satisfy the requirements outlined in the troubleshooting section.

Comment: I have pasted the header in the question.

Comment: From the troubleshooting section, the server headers should include the content length, the content type and support range requests. Your response headers do not indicate support for range requests.